# Refactor for less repetition

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I'm writing a script that makes several calls to our database (postgres) using methods contained in ClassroomDAL. The output of those database calls are then used to augment a summaryData hash.

However - I feel like I'm creating a ton of repetition and unsure of how to address. Would greatly appreciate any suggestions!

```
summaryData = {}

adaptiveQuestions = ClassroomDAL.adaptiveQuestions(conn, district_ids_postgres, options.start_date, options.end_date)
    targetedQuestions = ClassroomDAL.targetedQuestions(conn, district_ids_postgres, options.start_date, options.end_date)
    daysSpent = ClassroomDAL.daysSpent(conn, district_ids_postgres, options.start_date, options.end_date)
    getKSsDistrict = ClassroomDAL.getKSsDistrict(conn, district_ids_postgres, options.start_date, options.end_date)

    addStudentStats(summaryData, adaptiveQuestions, ["math_questions"])
    addStudentStats(summaryData, targetedQuestions, ["math_questions"])
    addStudentStats(summaryData, targetedQuestions, ["math_days", "classroom_grade"])
    addGradeLevelStats(summaryData, getKSsDistrict)
```

Comment: Instead of those being class methods taking arguments, maybe you need an object to store those common arguments. `classroom = ClassroomDAL.new( connection: conn, district_Ids: district_ids_postgres, start_date: options.start_date, end_date: options.end_date); adaptiveQuestions = classroom.adaptiveQuestions; ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the repeated arguments, you could use Array splat:

```
args = [conn, district_ids_postgres, options.start_date, options.end_date]
#then

adaptiveQuestions = ClassroomDAL.adaptiveQuestions *args
targetedQuestions = ClassroomDAL.targetedQuestions *args
daysSpent         = ClassroomDAL.daysSpent *args
getKSsDistrict    = ClassroomDAL.getKSsDistrict *args
```

You could then try and make things more smart by loop and send:

```
adaptiveQuestions, targetedQuestions, daysSpent, getKSsDistrict = ['adaptiveQuestions', 'targetedQuestions', 'daysSpent', 'getKSsDistrict'].each.map do |method| 
  ClassroomDAL.send(method, *args)
end
```

#### P.Ss

- Code not tested
- Sometimes, smarter syntax isn't very readable! it's a tradeoff
- you should use snake case instead of camel case in Ruby, i.e `days_spent instead` of `daysSpent`

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate it :)